# Django field choices: Avoid repeating value and human-readable form?

Tags: django

I have many `Field`s with a limited `choices` set. For all of them, the human-readable form is the same as the stored value of the field. For example,

```
color = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                 choices=[('blue', 'blue'),
                                          ('red', 'red'),
                                          ('yellow', 'yellow')
                                          ('green', 'green'),
                                          ('pink', 'pink')])
```

I don't want to double-type each choice. Is there a way I can write something like this:

```
color = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                 choices=['blue',
                                          'red',
                                          'yellow',
                                          'green',
                                          'pink'])
```

and Django automatically figures out that `'red'` is the value *and* the human-readable form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django is expecting a sequence of 2-tuples and you can't really make it *not* expect that (at least without modifying Django).

Fortunately, it's pretty easy to create this structure using a regular list and Python built-ins:

```
In [4]: choices = list('abcde')

In [5]: choices = tuple(zip(choices, choices))

In [6]: choices
Out[6]: (('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd'), ('e', 'e'))
```

As the OP points out in comments, you can also easily do this as a list comp:

```
choices = [(c, c) for c in 'abcde']
```

Comment: @ShangWang That would be fine. It would just be a `list` rather than a `tuple`, which might be less than ideal as that's mutable. Django doesn't care either way, so long as it's iterable.

Comment: can I write this somehow, but skipping the intermediary variable `choices`? that is, something like:

`color = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                 choices=[zip(...)])`

Comment: never mind, I figured it out: `color = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=[(c,c) for c in ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'])`